# Is "pls" considered unprofessional?

Tags: formality, abbreviations, register

Any where I talk to people on messages, emails, chats, etc... I find people tend to use the word "pls" instead of "please". Even my phone company texts me automatically saying "Pls call 321, You have 7 New VoiceMail messages". In business emails as well I am hearing this word. I find it unprofessional but is it just me who feels this way and should I use this or not for important emails and work?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Stack Exchange is not well-suited to solicitations for opinions, and there is no single authority on what is or isn't considered professional in all circumstances for all English speakers all around the world. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of the kinds of questions we can handle here.

Comment: Appropriate for informal contexts, particularly text messages where abbreviations are often used. Inappropriate for formal communications such as a job application or a written proposal.

Comment: Useful and acceptable if you have limited characters (e.g. text message, comment on SE, telegram?), but if character count is unlimited, using unnecessary abbreviations implies the writer doesn't have time for the reader (or is typing on their handheld device, but you can set up short cuts on those, too). That can be considered unprofessional or even rude... but [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) and all...

Comment: Pam is right on the money here. "Pls" is saying the exact opposite of "please". It shows disrespect to the person you are talking to, and communicates that you don't actually care for the thing you ask them for. Like, you can't even be arsed to type three more letters, that's how little you care about the thing or the person. And yes, if space is an issue, "pls" is certainly better than nothing at all, but even then, "please" is still much better. And also space is not an issue, like, ever. It's three letters. You have that space. You absolutely always do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**pls**

> abbreviation for please.  (used in e-mails and text messages)

[macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/pls)

As this is an abbreviation for *please*, use accordingly. Many feel it should not be used formally.  RSVP 
(abbreviation for répondez s'il vous plaît) is an abbreviation too, yet is found in formal and informal correspondence.